# GCC inline assembly constants (ARM)

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

Is there a good way to give constants to inline assembly code as "parameters"?
I'm trying to make a co-processor access functions.
I tried two approaches: macro-replacement and extensions.

The use is like this:

```
unsigned int read_ID_PFR1()
{
    READ_CP15(0, 0, 1, 1);
    return cp_reg_val;
}
```

The macro approach:

```
#define READ_CP15(opc, crn, crm, opc2) \
asm volatile (\
    "push {r0, r1}\n\t"\
    "mrc p15, opc, r0, crn, crm, opc2\n\t"\
    "ldr r1, =cp_reg_val\n\t"\
    "str r0, [r1]\n\t"\
    "pop {r0, r1}\n\t"\
    )
```

I think the parameters (opc, crn, ...) are not expanded because they are
used within quotation marks.

The extension approach looks like this:

```
#define WRITE_CP15(opc, crn, crm, opc2) \
    asm volatile (\
        "push {r0, r1}\n\t"\
        "ldr r1, =cp_reg_val\n\t"\
        "ldr r0, [r1]\n\t"\
        "mcr p15, %[op], r0, c%[rn], c%[rm], %[op2]\n\t"\
        "pop {r0, r1}\n\t"\
        ::[op]"I"(opc), [rn]"I"(crn), [rm]"I"(crm), [op2]"I"(opc2):\
    )
```

This seems to do better except the '#'-marks.
(c%[rn] expands to c#0)

Comment: Had that myself with `_BKPT` actually. You'll need a macro for this to work with any optimization setting. Funny sidenote: if not using `-O0`, this also works with inline functions. For `-O0`, gcc complains he might not be able to resolve the constant. Reason is apparently the inlining takes place before it checks the asm constraints (I used 'i' IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

Do not put push/pop in inline asm. Not only does it mean you're writing more junk in asm than you should have to; it also precludes using `"m"` type input/output constraints since the effective addresses could be stack-pointer-relative. Instead use something like:

```
asm volatile ("mrc p15, opc, %0, crn, crm, opc2" : "=r"(cp_reg_val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up a bit:

```
#define READ_CP15(retvar, opc, crn, crm, opc2) \
    asm volatile (\
        "mrc p15, %c[op], %[reg], c%c[rn], c%c[rm], %c[op2]\n\t"\
        :[reg] "=r" (retvar)\
        :[op]"I"(opc), [rn]"I"(crn), [rm]"I"(crm), [op2]"I"(opc2):\
    )
```

Those opc, crn, crm and opc2 need to be there. They are constants.
The output assembly is:

```
@ 252 "../instr_comm.c" 1
    mrc p15, 0, r0, c0, c1, 1
```

Answer (score -2):

McMurphy stroke again. I spent some hours figuring out, but now that I sent the question I found out that 'c' between the '%' and '[name]' does it - looses the '#'.

This works:

```
#define READ_CP15(opc, crn, crm, opc2) \
    asm volatile (\
        "push {r0, r1}\n\t"\
        "mrc p15, %c[op], r0, c%c[rn], c%c[rm], %c[op2]\n\t"\
        "ldr r1, =cp_reg_val\n\t"\
        "str r0, [r1]\n\t"\
        "pop {r0, r1}\n\t"\
        ::[op]"I"(opc), [rn]"I"(crn), [rm]"I"(crm), [op2]"I"(opc2):\
    )
```

Checked from the (temporary) .s file.

Comment: Why do you have two answers for your own question? Just delete one.

Comment: Olaf, my second answer was to R..'s answer.

Comment: This is no forum. Just comment on his answer (still not sure why). However, he is perfectly right about the push/pop stuff. Note that the compiler cannot follow what you did in your assember code. It is bascially just copied (well, with some additions, of course).

Comment: That was originally the idea - clean everything such that the C-part never saw any effects of running that assembly, except the result that emerges in a variable.

Comment: But the gcc will do that for you! That way, it can much better optimize the surrounding code, for instance it can combine any push/pop required with some it has to do anway. Or just not need the push/pop by using other registers. Well, that is your code, I will not continue a fruitless discussion. I have the strong impression you do not fully understand the idea of inline assembly.